# Overlapping faces / texture painting

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

i am learning the blender program following BlenderGuru videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nht2RoYBUfA I was drawing the donut texture. When I use the brush I don't have a single stroke but fragmented or reproduced in other points. the problem should be overlapping faces?
Does anyone know how to do? help me please

[image]

[image]

Comment: Salman has given a solution, you can also select the whole mesh, then select one face to make it active, and unwrap with the Follow Active Quads option

Answer (score 2):

[image]

HI .
1- Just make two cuts like Picture by selecting Edge loops and Press CTRL + E > mark seam
2- go to uv and press U to unfold it

GL .

Comment: Thank you mannnn <3 
it was easier than I expected
So is it normal for this to happen or did I do something wrong before?
in the tutorial he doesn't have this problem and has a square lattice

Answer (score 0):

By default a torus has its default UV as you can see below :

[image]

As time as you make seem cut and unfold it will change .

If you need to your mesh looks smooth normal just right click on your mesh in object mode and select shade smooth . you can even bake your own normal from a high poly mesh too .